# Unable to find matching profile against choices error on hapi version 5.x for custom profiles

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am using custom profiles for validating bundle resource of type document. While using reference to other resources within bundle , I am getting the below error :

```
"Bundle.entry[0].resource.ofType(Composition).subject Unable to find matching profile for Patient/1 among choices: http://example.com/fhir/r4/StructureDefinition/Patient".
```

This error is only coming on `HAPI Version 5.x` and not coming on `HAPI Version 4.2.0` I am using `FHIR version R4 v4.0.1`.

It doesn't seem to be problem with code , as code is same for both HAPI versions mentioned above.

Is it Bug in Hapi ? or am i missing some point regarding referencing.

Comment: The validation continues to improve, so it's possible an error is caught in the newer release that wasn't in the old one.  Is the error valid?

Comment: No the error doesn't seem to be valid. When i logged actual information messages also, it logged, that  "Bundle.entry[0].resource.ofType(Composition).subject Details for Patient/1 matching against Profile " . So messages seems to be contradicting.

Comment: Then you'll need to post your example resources and profiles somewhere so we can reproduce it